# AWK: to sum colums and insert output in new row of csv file

Tags: bash, awk

Hi I have a csv file with below data in it.

8/22/2013   1,417,196,108

8/23/2013   1,370,586,883

8/24/2013   1,362,561,606

8/25/2013   1,177,575,904

8/26/2013   1,228,394,403

8/27/2013   1,276,168,499

8/28/2013   1,265,333,615

I want a script that can help me to sum 2nd column and insert result in next row, so the output should look like:

8/22/2013   1,417,196,108

8/23/2013   1,370,586,883

8/24/2013   1,362,561,606

8/25/2013   1,177,575,904

8/26/2013   1,228,394,403

8/27/2013   1,276,168,499

8/28/2013   1,265,333,615

Total       9,097,817,018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Pure bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r _ curNumber; do
    (( answer += ${curNumber//,/} ))
done < file.csv

(( start = (${#answer} % 3 == 0 ? 3 : ${#answer} % 3) ))
echo -n "${answer:0:start}"
for ((i = start; i < ${#answer}; i += 3)); do
    echo -n ",${answer:i:3}"
done
echo
```

Answer (score 3):

the tricky part of this question is the thousand separator.

Try this line:

```
awk '{print;gsub(/,/,"");s+=$2}END{printf "Total %'\''d\n",s}' file
```

test with your data:

```
kent$  awk '{print;gsub(/,/,"");s+=$2}END{printf "Total %'\''d\n",s}' f
8/22/2013 1,417,196,108

8/23/2013 1,370,586,883

8/24/2013 1,362,561,606

8/25/2013 1,177,575,904

8/26/2013 1,228,394,403

8/27/2013 1,276,168,499

8/28/2013 1,265,333,615
Total 9,097,817,018
```

Comment: `the tricky part of this question is the thousand separator.` Yep! ;) ...  Really nice answer

Comment: Hi,
awk script worked well, what if we consider no commas are there in file ? tHEN IT IS GIVING TOTAL AS 0.

$ awk '{print;gsub(/,/,"");s+=$2}END{printf "Total %'\''d\n",s}' file

8/22/2013,1417196108

8/23/2013,1370586883

8/24/2013,1362561606

8/25/2013,1177575904

8/26/2013,1228394403

8/27/2013,1276168499

8/28/2013,1265333615

Total 0

Any suggestions ?

Comment: @user2043380 then why you wrote `Hi I have a csv file with below data in it.` in your question? You didn't mention that case at all, how can I imagine what different cases do you have? anyway, I guess in your test, you not only removed the thousand separators, you change the field-separator from space to comma, that's why you got total 0. if FS=comma, you could try `awk -F, '..same code' file`